# Integer hash table with modulo sys.maxsize

Tags: python, data-structures, hash

I'm working on something for my coursework that requires me to use various different data structures. I'm given a prompt that states that I must create a package delivery system in which each package has it's own unique identifier and to use 'one of the data structures from class' (everything from red/black trees to hash tables) to store them in.

My idea was to use said hash table and just mod it with sys.maxsize similar to this:

```
def myobject():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
    def getHash(self):
        return self.id % sys.maxsize;
```

Is this an acceptable way to deal with hashing integers? There's no real case in which I will have anywhere near sys.maxsize amount of items in the table.

If this is not a decent way to do it, which data structure would be better, or hashing algorithm

Comment: I read that within python an integer can be larger than a word, but I don't know how it handles access within a hash table so I'm not sure if it maps to a word size.